# jQuery Compare Div Contents and Remove Anything that is Duplicated Data

Tags: jquery, html, duplicates, compare

Is it possible to compare the contents of 2 divs and if any of the content matches, remove it from the 2nd instance?

In the example below we'd see that "2018 Spring Conference" is already appears in the h2 so we'd target and remove it from the list items below.

Ideally we'd be left with "Member Registration", "Non-Member Registration" and "Guest Registration".

```
<h2>2018 Spring Conference and Registration</h2>
<ul class="prod-options-list">
<li>
    <h4><a href="#">2018 Spring Conference Member Registration</a></h4>
</li>
<li>
    <h4><a href="#">2018 Spring Conference Non-Member Registration</a></h4>
</li>
<li>
    <h4><a href="#">2018 Spring Conference Guest Registration</a></h4>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do a .each of each h4 under prod-options-list, compare to the previous, if it's the same remove it and move forward

Comment: The expected result in `li`s is "Member", "Non-Member" and "Guest"?

Comment: Close @CommercialSuicide. I'm looking for "Member Registration",  "Non-Member Registration" and "Guest Registration". Sorry, I should have specified. Will edit.

Comment: @clearshot66 I don't follow.

Comment: Seems like a use-case that could lead to problems  if you are talking dynamically. Why can't you just update the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, using jQuery ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q37nnem9/))

```
var h2text = $('h2').text().split(' ');

$('a').each(function () {
    var t = $(this).text();

  h2text.forEach(function (e) {
      t = t.replace(e, "");
  });

  $(this).text(t); // this removes any match of repeated words

  // if you need to put "Registration", then use this line instead of the above:
  $(this).text(t + 'Registration');


});
```